# Google TV Chrome Browser does not render JQuery-UI .buttonset() radio buttons correctly

Tags: jquery-ui-button, google-tv

I use the latest version of Jquery-UI -- and not the one designed specifically for Google TV (as the google TV version is essentially completely different product).

For the most part, all the jquery and jquery-UI is compatible with the google TV chrome browser, with the exception of the radio buttons which have a .buttonset() call to style them.

While it does show the stylized radios (rounded corners, toggle button style, gradient background, etc), it turns out that the actual HTML radio (the physical dot box) is floating into the left margin of the page, aligned on the X access with the stylized version of the button. Clicking the actual radio button does in fact register it as being clicked, as does clicking the stylized version (which I'm guessing is just a load of CSS being applied to the corresponding  tag).

Now, like I said, everything works the way it's supposed to, but it's ugly and perhaps confusing to have a random floating radio button far outside the form. Are there any work arounds or CSS hacks to fix this? Unfortunately, I do not have the ability to create a specific view logic for google TVs to optimize it for google TV -- mostly because of time and the site doesnt have an MVC architecture, so having multiple views is not terribly easy thing to pull off.

Any ideas, ladies and gentlemen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked someone to look at it, and was asked for your URL.  If you could post one, it would be helpful to getting you an answer.

Comment: I wish I could. All the code is within a protected access part of the tool. The tool (and by extension, the URLs and username/password credentials) is sadly protected by my CDA. The best I could do is a screenshot and the HTML mark up of the radio buttons. Will that suffice?

Comment: Probably the quickest way to an answer is at http://code.google.com/tv/web/forum.html aka googletv-web@googlegroups.com, post your screenshot there if it doesn't have anything confidential in it.